# ZUUIRevealController shows blanks space above window

Tags: ios

So I implemented ZUUIRevealController to create a separate menu, this all works nicely, but it seems to have some problems with the rearViewController, have a look at this image:
[image]

As you can see there is a blank space shown, exactly the height of the status bar, I don't know why.

Nothing special is happening when implementing this:

```
SortViewController *sortViewController = [[SortViewController alloc] init]; 

ZUUIRevealController *revealController = [[ZUUIRevealController alloc] initWithFrontViewController:self.tabBarController rearViewController:sortViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = revealController;
```

SortViewController is a UITableViewController.

Comment: try initWithFrontViewController:self

Answer (score 2):

Check this out :
Use this code in ur AppDelegate.m file -

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window = window;

    FrontViewController *frontViewController = [[FrontViewController alloc] init];
    RearViewController *rearViewController = [[RearViewController alloc] init];

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:frontViewController];

    RevealController *revealController = [[RevealController alloc] initWithFrontViewController:navigationController rearViewController:rearViewController];
    self.viewController = revealController;

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Hopefully dis solves ur problem and i m rewarded with 50+ BOUNTY :)

Comment: I'm not sure how this pseudo code is supposed to address the problem. An explanation would help.

Answer (score 2):

Just had this same issue and found the fix. Go to the `UITableViewController` you are using as the rear view, in the attributes inspector, under View Controller, there is a checkbox for Layout wants full screen. This gets rid of the blank bit above the `tableview` in your `rearViewController`.

Answer (score -2):

I just found that that if I use a normal view it works, before I just use a UITableView, that seemed to give problems.